# Vector operations on Eigen Array of Vectors

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, eigen

I have a 2D Eigen Array where each item in the array is a 3-element Eigen Vector (e.g. a velocity field over a surface).

I want to multiply each each element of the 2D array with a 3-element Eigen RowVector, effectively taking the dot product.

```
    Eigen::Array<Eigen::Vector3d, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> velField(5, 5);
    Eigen::Vector3d n;
    // ... initialisation of n and velField not shown

    Eigen::Array<double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> result(5, 5);
    result = n.transpose() * velField;
```

This gives a compile error YOU MIXED DIFFERENT NUMERIC TYPES. However, if I don't *assign* the result, but just compute it:

```
    n.transpose() * velField;
```

it compiles. What is the correct return type for 'result' - or how else can I fix this?

**EDIT**

The same problem can be observed in this simpler case (multiplying by a double):

```
Eigen::Array<Eigen::Vector3d, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> velField(5, 5);
// ... initialisation of velField not shown
Eigen::Array<Eigen::Vector3d, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> result(5, 5);
result = 3.0 * velField;
```

However the same code works when using `std::complex<double>` instead of `Eigen::Vector3d`:

```
Eigen::Array<std::complex<double>, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> velField(5, 5);
// ... initialisation of velField not shown
Eigen::Array<std::complex<double>, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic> result(5, 5);
result = 3.0 * velField;
```

I wonder why it works for `std::complex` but not with `Eigen::Vector3d`. Both types define the operator `*` with a `double`.

Comment: Which eigen version? 2 or 3? Which compiler you are using?

Comment: Eigen v3 and MSVS2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After further reading, I found an answer:

According to the [reference documentation of the matrix class](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Matrix.html), the first template parameter `_Scalar` is:

```
_Scalar: matrix_tparam_scalar Numeric type, e.g. float, double, int or std::complex<float>.
User defined sclar types are supported as well.
```

It links to this [page](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizingEigen.html#user_defined_scalars). It lists the requirements for the "custom scalar types". In the above example [`Eigen::NumTraits`](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/structEigen_1_1NumTraits.html) for `<Vector3d>` is missing. It can't be implemented properly for `Vector3d`, so one should only store types that represent scalars inside an `Eigen::Matrix`/`Eigen::Array`.

---

Update:

The line without assignment `n.transpose() * velField;` works because of lazy evalutation. It also works when doing this (in C++11):

```
auto result = n.transpose() * velField;
```

But it has done no calculation at that point (check the type of `result` in the debugger). As soon as you use `result` it will fail the same way than in your first example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So it works for std::complex only because this has been implemented as a special case within Eigen? (If complex numbers 'just worked' automatically, I can't see why a Vector3D wouldn't).

Comment: Yes, `Eigen::NumTraits<std::complex<T> >` has been defined in the Eigen library, whereas `Eigen::NumTraits<Vector3d >` is not defined.  Given that `Vector3d` is not a scalar from a vector field (in the linear algebra sense), it's not really possible to add an `Eigen::NumTraits<Vector3d >`. What is the "real" part of a Vector3d?

Answer (score 1):

This is not allowed. I'd recommend to store velField as a Matrix, i.e., a 1D array of 3D vectors, and then use standard linear algebra operators.

Comment: Can you elaborate why it is not allowed? Do you have a explanation why it works when using `std::complex<double>` instead of `Eigen::Vector3d`?